# Azure Website: Upload button is missing

Tags: azure

I used to upload a package to an existing Azure website using the Upload button in the management portal. The button seems to be missing now.

How can I upload a package manually?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the concept of Windows Azure website. you can't publish package directly as you can in Cloud Service, Instead you need to configure **GIT** OR **TFS** deployment option and using that you can upload you application on windows azure websites (WAWS).

For more details read this [article](http://blog.ntotten.com/2012/06/07/10-things-about-windows-azure-web-sites/)

Answer (score 0):

The upload feature was removed from the portal. You can upload/deploy your website using a wide range of methods: GIT, FTP, TFS, Web Matrix. Hope that helps.